# Shell script gets validated online, does not work on Travis CI (unexpected token fi)

Tags: shell, travis-ci

I have the following shell script that gets validated online, but fails on Travis CI:

```
if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" == "false" ]; then
if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "master" ]; then

  # define some variables
  GH_USER=skiwi2
  GH_REPO=TCG

  # get info about all releases
  echo -e "Getting info about previous releases"
  curl -X GET -H "Authorization: token ${GH_TOKEN}" \
       "https://api.github.com/repos/${GH_USER}/${GH_REPO}/releases" > json.txt

  # extract info only about only "latest-release" tag
  cat json.txt |jq 'map(select (.tag_name == "latest-master"))' > latest.txt

  # get id of release
  ID_TO_DELETE=`cat latest.txt |jq '.[0].id'`

  # delete previous release
  echo -e "Deleting release number ${ID_TO_DELETE}"
  curl -X DELETE -H "Authorization: token ${GH_TOKEN}" \
     "https://api.github.com/repos/${GH_USER}/${GH_REPO}/releases/${ID_TO_DELETE}"

  # delete previous tag
  curl -X DELETE -H "Authorization: token ${GH_TOKEN}" \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/${GH_USER}/${GH_REPO}/git/refs/tags/latest-master"


  echo -e "Creating a release\n"
  curl -X POST -H "Authorization: token ${GH_TOKEN}" \
      -d '{"tag_name": "latest-master", "target_commitish": "master", "name": "master-${TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER}", "body": "Automatic release based on latest commit to master branch generated by Travis CI.", "draft": false, "prerelease": true}' "https://api.github.com/repos/${GH_USER}/${GH_REPO}/releases" > json.txt
  IDDI=`cat json.txt | jq '.id'`

  echo -e "Uploading JAR\n"
  curl -X POST -H "Authorization: token ${GH_TOKEN}" \
     -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.manifold-preview" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/java-archive" \
     --data-binary /home/travis/build/{$GH_USER}/{$GH_REPO}/target/TCG-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
     "https://uploads.github.com/repos/${GH_USER}/${GH_REPO}/releases/${IDDI}/assets?name=tcg-master-${TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER}.jar"

  echo -e "Done uploading\n"

fi
fi
```

It fails with:

```
./upload_binaries.sh: line 44: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./upload_binaries.sh: line 44: `fi'
```

However to my knowledge this should not be unexpected. Unfortunately I am not too experienced with shell, can it be that older versions required a different syntax?

Line 44 is the very last line of the script, the one containing the last `fi`.

Moreover, all variables that are not defined in this script, are being defined in some other way by the Travis CI.

Comment: Try to replace `--data-binary /home/travis/build/{$GH_USER}/{$GH_REPO}/target/TCG-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \ ` with `--data-binary "/home/travis/build/{$GH_USER}/{$GH_REPO}/target/TCG-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" \ `

Comment: Also, it should `${GH_USER}` not `{$GH_USER}`. Same with `{$GH_REPO}`.

Comment: That's a lot of [useless `cat`s](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: Does your script lack a proper [shebang line](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))?

Comment: I have used another existing script as a huge inspiration source and that one (judging by the github releases) seems to be working properly there. I'll incorporate all changes suggested here though.

Comment: @GergoErdosi Strange about the `${X}` vs `{$X}`, as this same script seems to be working in another (not mine) repo.

Comment: @skiwi Well, it might work, because `{}` creates a block and `$GH_USER` returns the value of that variable. But what you wanted to do here is just string substitution, which has the syntax `${GH_USER}`.

Comment: @GergoErdosi If it is of any help, this version seems to be working (my source of inspiration): https://github.com/WagicProject/wagic/blob/master/upload-binaries.sh

Comment: @skiwi Try to incorporate the changes and see if it helps. My best is guess is the missing double quotes.

Comment: @GergoErdosi Didn't change anything unfortunately. I'm really lost at where it could be going wrong. I'm pretty much only repeating things that the other script has succesfully done. Even a "wrong" `${VAR}` block inside a quoted link has been done and was working. Nor do the scripts have the shebang line in front of them.

Comment: @skiwi Can't see what's wrong then. I suggest to remove every line in that script and add them back one by one. That way you will find out which one causes the problem.

Comment: @GergoErdosi I can't fully trace back the exact issue, but I suppose it was because I was using Windows line endings, while Travis CI runs the scripts on an Unix variant hence warranting Unix line endings.

Answer (score 0):

Try **one** equal sign for test.

```
if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" = "false" ]; then
if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "master" ]; then
...
```

On man page for test we can read:

```
 string1 = string2           True if the strings string1 and string2 are identical.
```